# How to remove quotes in active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to retrieve records from multiple tables based on collection of ids suing the 
below query, it is working fine.

**ACTIVE RECORD QUERY:**

> Song.order("songs.id desc").
>             includes(:artist).includes(:album).
>             joins("LEFT JOIN artists ON songs.artist_id = artists.id").
>             joins("LEFT JOIN albums ON songs.album_id = albums.id").
>             where("(songs.id)
>
> > IN (#{song_ids*','})
>
> AND (LOWER(songs.title) LIKE :term OR LOWER(artists.name) LIKE :term
>   OR LOWER(albums.title) LIKE :term)",
>             :term => "%#{terms[index].downcase}%")

**PG QUERY OUTPUT:**

> SELECT "songs".* FROM "songs" LEFT JOIN artists ON songs.artist_id =
>   artists.id LEFT JOIN albums ON songs.album_id = albums.id WHERE (
>
> > (songs.id) IN (4,5,28,37,46,48)
>
> AND (LOWER(songs.title) LIKE '%wo%' OR LOWER(artists.name) LIKE
>   '%wo%' OR LOWER(albums.title) LIKE '%wo%')) ORDER BY songs.id desc

But while I was trying to modify the query as below

**ACTIVE RECORD QUERY:**

> Song.order("songs.id desc").
>             includes(:artist).includes(:album).
>             joins("LEFT JOIN artists ON songs.artist_id = artists.id").
>             joins("LEFT JOIN albums ON songs.album_id = albums.id").
>             where("(songs.id)
>
> > IN (:song_ids)
>
> AND (LOWER(songs.title) LIKE :term OR LOWER(artists.name) LIKE :term
>   OR LOWER(albums.title) LIKE :term)",

```
      :term => "%#{terms[index].downcase}%",:song_ids => song_ids*',')
```

**PG QUERY OUTPUT:**

> SELECT "songs".* FROM "songs" LEFT JOIN artists ON songs.artist_id =
>   artists.id LEFT JOIN albums ON songs.album_id = albums.id WHERE (
>
> > (songs.id) IN ('4,5,28,37,46,48')
>
> AND (LOWER(songs.title) LIKE '%wo%' OR LOWER(artists.name) LIKE
>   '%wo%' OR LOWER(albums.title) LIKE '%wo%')) ORDER BY songs.id desc

Because of the single quotes the above query doesn't working.

Comment: `IN (:song_ids)`, :song_ids: song_ids`
You're converting it to a string and joining it yourself so it's going to be quoted. Don't join it yourself

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `:song_ids => song_ids*','` with `:song_ids => song_ids`.

In your original code, you converted song_ids to string, which was escaped and single quotes were put to mark that it was a string. This passes only array as an argument and rails will do the magic and convert it to something like this 4,5,28,37,46,48 (you still need your parentheses).

Comment: Would you be able to expand a little on how this will resolve the problem?